# Reforming table structure of columns possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot-table

I have bee at this all day. I have played around with a lot of MySQL code and I am either inept, or not very good at coding..

**I have a table**

```
name     id       type      amount
=================================
apple    21       cars      67
apple    21       bikes     85
apple    21       skates    557
apple    21       pajs      56
orange   34       bikes     345
orange   34       disks     678
orange   34       cars      234
orange   34       pajs      5678
```

**I want to write a query that will bring back the table in this form**

```
name    id cars bikes skates pajas disks
=========================================
apple   21 67   85    557    56    0    
orange  34 234  345   0      5678  678
```

I really just have no clue where to start. Sorry if this is noobie question but MySQL is really hard to conceptualize sometimes.

Comment: It's called a "pivot table". Suggest to do a Google search on that - there are plenty of questions here that also cover the topic.

Comment: Here is a [SO post on creating pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table). [There is a link given for a tutorial to create pivot tables. Have a look at that](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `PreparedStatement`

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(ID),MAX(case when type = ''',
      type,
      ''' then amount ELSE NULL end) AS ',
       type
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM table1 GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f9a6/1)

Alternatively,

```
SELECT  name,
        MAX(ID) ID,
        MAX(case when type = 'cars' THEN amount ELSE NULL end) AS cars,
        MAX(case when type = 'bikes' THEN amount ELSE NULL end) AS bikes,
        MAX(case when type = 'skates' THEN amount ELSE NULL end) AS skates,
        MAX(case when type = 'pajas' THEN amount ELSE NULL end) AS pajas,
        MAX(case when type = 'disks' THEN amount ELSE NULL end) AS disks
FROM table1 
GROUP BY name;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdbbc/1)

Comment: John Woo this is the second time you have helped me out with lightning speed code working perfectly. I don't even know what to say. Thank you so much.

Comment: [Displaying zero instead of NULL in PreparedStatement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f9a6/4)

Comment: Absolutely flawless. Programmers like you is what I aspire to.

Comment: Hey John, can I ask you a question? The query works great. But when I attempt here it does not work? The table structure is ok. Am I doing something wrong? sqlfiddle.com/#!2/264e8/1 –

Comment: I think I know why. The procedure creates a table with a set of columns with names based on the the `status` field. If another `user_name` has a different number of rows with `status` then it will create more or less fields for that user and attempt to join it to the table. this one is going to be tough.

Comment: @JohnWoo fyi, you don't need the `max(id)`, if you include it in the `GROUP BY` it will work without the additional aggregate.